# iptables No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I'm trying to simple block DDoS attacks by using:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 27015 -m limit --limit 10/s --limit-burst 20 -j DROP
```

But getting:

**iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.**

Any help? Info?

Debian 9

Comment: Debian 9, but is it Debian 9's kernel too? What is the result of `uname -a` ?

Comment: Module loaded ( or compiled in)?

Comment: Have you tried adding -t filter or -t mangle? Sometimes you need to give the table name, and there are more than one table with an INPUT chain.

Answer (score 3):

## Issue at Hand

It appears that you do not have the correct kernel modules loaded to use iptables or the iptables command you have issued is too vague for iptables to interpret.

I have found a few sources ([link 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793272/iptables-forward-port-error-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name) [link 2](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name-4175596511/)) that reference being more specific as to which table the rule will apply to your cleaning up the order of the flags to fix this issue.

I have also found a few sources ([link 3](https://serverfault.com/questions/523731/how-to-fix-iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name/524471) [link 4](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-567196-highlight-.html)) that suggest that you could be missing the kernel modules.

#### 1. Missing flag in the iptables command

According to the issue faced by others in [link 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793272/iptables-forward-port-error-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name) and [link 2](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name-4175596511/), the issue may be due to your command being too ambiguous to be properly interpreted. Adding a `-t nat` option may assist in this.

```
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -p udp --dport 27015 -m limit --limit 10/s --limit-burst 20 -j DROP
```

Save your rule and reboot, or simply restart the iptables service. That should solve the issue. [Link 2](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name-4175596511/) deals more with the difference between `POSTROUTING` and `PREROUTING`. I would make sure you know which one you would prefer to use and maybe follow one of the fixes they suggest.

#### 2. Missing kernel options

If the first option did not work then you may be missing the correct kernel modules. According to [link 3](https://serverfault.com/questions/523731/how-to-fix-iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name/524471) and [link 4](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-567196-highlight-.html), you may need to initialize the missing features.

Using `lsmod`, you can list all installed modules. The modules you are missing may be related to xt_multiport and xt_comment. Following the [gentoo forum post](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-567196-highlight-.html), there could be an additional set of kernel modules you need to enable too. Using `modprobe` you can try to enable `netfilter`, `ip_tables`, `ip_conntrack`, etc.

I will include links to both the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module) and a [Tecmint article](https://www.tecmint.com/load-and-unload-kernel-modules-in-linux/) on how to enable kernel modules. [This link explains](https://serverfault.com/questions/326687/what-is-the-correct-way-to-load-modules-for-iptables-on-centos-6) the correct way to set up iptables for CentOS using `modprobe`.

> `/etc/sysconfig/modules/*.modules` or `/etc/rc.modules`
>
> ```
>  echo "modprobe ip_conntrack" >> /path/to/modules/iptables.modules
>  chmod +x /path/to/modules/iptables.modules
> ```

Please use `lsmod` too look up what you have enabled and verify what you are missing before running any of these commands. In the long run it could be safer to make sure your kernel is up to date first and *is the supported kernel provided by Debian*.

## Conclusion

Please make sure that you have formatted your iptables command correctly. There are many resources out there to do what you desire, as long as you format things correctly. I am also including a link to [this issue with Docker on GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/16816) just in case you actually using a Docker image based on Debian.

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I highly suggest you read through each link I have provided thoroughly before attempting the commands. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!